# Can't get a scenario's filename from scenario.file in Cucumber 2.3.2

Tags: ruby, cucumber, hook, scenarios

I have this code in Rails app /features/support/hooks.rb:

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    filename = "#{FAILED_DIR_PATH}/failed--#{scenario.file.gsub("features/","").gsub("/","-")}--#{scenario.line}.html"
    Capybara.save_page filename
  end
end
```

If the scenario at line `12` in file `/features/user_features/user_login.feature` failed then, instead of the default capybara page dump filename

```
tmp/capybara/capybara-5654648798738734.html
```

the dump would be saved with a better filename:

```
tmp/capybara/failed--user_features-user_login.feature--12.html
```

so if there are many failures I immediately know which dump is the right one.

This worked in Cucumber 1.3.2.

Today I updated gems and got `Cucumber 2.3.2` and got this error:

```
 undefined method `file' for #<Cucumber::RunningTestCase::Scenario:0x007f9598abb230>
```

If I debug it, `scenario` has just these methods:

```
Cucumber::RunningTestCase::Scenario#methods: 

accept_hook?  exception  failed?  outline?  passed?  skip_invoke!  source_tag_names  source_tags  status  title   with_result
```

The only place where I can find the name of the file is in `scenario.exception.backtrace` (deeply buried beneath Capybara files).

**Is there now any possibility of getting the scenario file path and the number of the line where the scenario started?**

Comment: Thanks Dave for incredible corrections and improvement of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cucumber 2, the `file` and `line` are attributes of the `scenario`'s `location`, not of the `scenario` itself. Replace `scenario.file` with `scenario.location.file` and `scenario.line` with `scenario.location.line`.